# Multiple classes, unable to return desired page(s)

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook

first want to say that I am a first time poster so I am sorry in advance if any parts of my question or the way it is asked/presented "sucks." With that being said, I've been trying to scrape a table from barchart.com use jupyter and beautifulsoup that is on multiple pages and while I have been successful in returning the entire page as a whole, I haven't had much luck trying to return the specific pages I need. I did include some images, the first three of which reference the elements that I am currently "choosing" from to use:

[the 'div' element that highlights the entire table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUX52.png)

[another 'div' element within the first 'div' that also has the entire table I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQPCp.png)

[The 'table' element that I would use but it doesn't include the left most column that includes the tickers/stock symbols](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1to9.png)

Regardless of what I have tried to put in my code, I always get a "[]" back and haven't been able to figure out how to write the multiple parts of each 'div' or 'table', if that makes sense.

[Code pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMger.png)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request

stonks_url = Request('https://www.barchart.com/options/unusual-activity/stocks', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
stonks_data = urlopen(stonks_url)
stonks_html = stonks_data.read()
stonks_data.close()
page_soup = soup(stonks_html, 'html.parser')

uoa_table = page_soup.findAll('tbody', {'data-ng-repeat': 'rows in content'})
print(uoa_table)
```

Thanks in advance to any advice or guidance!

Comment: html code with javascript on load that requests won't access.

Comment: @SamsulIslam I think I get what you mean. as in it won't work because I am using an html parser for data that is in javascript? correct? is there a way around it within the code or would I have to rewrite a completely new file?

Comment: You can use selenium to get the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this page is not working with javascript request you need to use the selenium and get the page source of the page and use it for processing the table

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
from selenium import webdriver

driver= webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.barchart.com/options/unusual-activity/stocks')
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')


# get text
text = soup.get_text()

print(text)
```

Comment: thanks! I got it to work relatively based on this frame work. I still need to find out how to get the specific page/table but I think I can manage that.